How to mock a read-only method with pytest-mock
I want to test my client and server implementations, which use a socket for communication. So I tried to use pytest-mock to replace the recv and sendall methods of socket to not have to deal with establishing a real connection.
I came up with this code:
from collections import deque
from threading import Lock
import socket
from time import sleep
from typing import Deque

import pytest
from pytest_mock import MockFixture

from comms import Comms


def mocked_socket(mocker: MockFixture):
    connection = socket.socket()
    backing_store: Deque[int] = deque()
    lock = Lock()

    def receiver(n: int):
        with lock:
            # NOTE: To better simulate socket behaviour, we allow the sender to refill the backing store for the duration of connection.timeout.
            bl = len(backing_store)
            if bl == 0 and connection.timeout is not None:
                lock.release()
                sleep(connection.timeout)
                lock.acquire()

            # FIXME: We raise a timeout here, even if connection.timeout is None (i.e. socket is blocking). This is, because returning an empty bytes object is interpreted as the other side having terminated the connection. If we wanted to model socket even more closely, we should have a condition variable for reception, that this thread can wait on.
            bl = len(backing_store)
            if bl == 0:
                raise socket.timeout

            n_cap = min(len(backing_store), n)
            return bytes(backing_store.popleft() for _ in range(n_cap))

    def sender(buffer: bytes):
        with lock:
            backing_store.extend(buffer)

    mocker.patch.object(connection, "recv", wraps=receiver)
    mocker.patch.object(connection, "sendall", wraps=sender)

    return connection


def test(mocker: MockFixture):
    connection = mocked_socket(mocker)
    server = Comms(connection)
    client = Comms(connection)

    # ... whatever I want to test

However, when I try to run pytest, I get a bunch of these errors:
        self.temp_original = original
        self.is_local = local
        self._exit_stack = contextlib.ExitStack()
        try:
>           setattr(self.target, self.attribute, new_attr)
E           AttributeError: 'socket' object attribute 'recv' is read-only

/usr/lib/python3.12/unittest/mock.py:1567: AttributeError

So it seems what I am trying to do is impossible, because patching recv/sendall requires deleting their original implementations, which does not work because they are marked as read-only.
I have found How to mock a readonly property with mock?, but that only deals with mocking properties, not methods.
I have never used pytest, unittest.mock etc. before, so is there a simple solution I am missing? Is what I am trying to do even the correct approach?

You can't patch a real socket. But it seems like you are trying to replace a real socket with an instance of mocked_socket, which does not itself need to patch an instance of socket. When, for example, mocked_socket.recv is called, that doesn't mean you need to patch (or use at all) a real socket.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but why can't socket be mocked instead and just perform your mocks around that? Doing something like patch("socket.socket", spec=True) or similar should suffice? I've done that in the past and have been able to handle recv just fine.

I have executed your code with some modification in my system The bigger difference is that I have not used pytest: in my test code I have used only the standard package unittest.
Files test_socket.py and comms.py
First of all I show you my test code (contained in a file called test_socket.py) and after I'm going to explain it:
import unittest
from unittest import mock

from collections import deque
from threading import Lock
import socket
from time import sleep
from typing import Deque

from comms import Comms

backing_store: Deque[int] = deque()
lock = Lock()

def receiver(n: int):
    print(f"Start receiver(n) = {n}")
    with lock:
        # NOTE: To better simulate socket behaviour, we allow the sender to refill the backing store for the duration of connection.timeout.
        bl = len(backing_store)
        if bl == 0 and Comms.timeout is not None:
            lock.release()
            sleep(Comms.timeout)
            lock.acquire()

        # FIXME: We raise a timeout here, even if connection.timeout is None (i.e. socket is blocking). This is, because returning an empty bytes object is interpreted as the other side having terminated the connection. If we wanted to model socket even more closely, we should have a condition variable for reception, that this thread can wait on.
        bl = len(backing_store)
        if bl == 0:
            raise socket.timeout

        n_cap = min(len(backing_store), n)

        print(f"End receiver(n) = {n}")

        return bytes(backing_store.popleft() for _ in range(n_cap))


def sender(buffer: bytes):
    print(f"Start sender(buffer) = {buffer}")
    with lock:
        backing_store.extend(buffer)
    print(f"End sender(buffer) = {buffer}")

class SocketTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.mock_socket = mock.create_autospec(socket.socket)
        self.server = Comms(self.mock_socket)
        self.client = Comms(self.mock_socket)

    def test_01(self):
        buffer = b"12345"
        self.mock_socket.sendall.return_value = sender(buffer)
        self.client.sender(buffer)

    def test_02(self):
        n = 5
        self.mock_socket.recv.return_value = receiver(n)
        self.server.receiver(n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

I have also defined an example file comms.py in the same folder of the file test_socket.py which simulates your file comms.py where it is defined the class Comms:
class Comms:

    timeout = 10

    def __init__(self, connection: socket.socket):
        self.connection = connection
    
    def sender(self, buffer: bytes):
        self.connection.sendall(buffer)

    def receiver(self, n: int):
        self.connection.recv(n)

The __init__() method of Comms waits an instance of socket.socket().
Output execution
Now I'll show how to execute the code (not by pytest command) and its output:
> python /path/to/test_socket.py

Start sender(buffer) = b'12345'
End sender(buffer) = b'12345'
Start receiver(n) = 5
End receiver(n) = 5
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.027s

OK

The output shows that methods sendall() and recv() of the socket object are mocking by the function sender(buffer: bytes) and recv(n: int).
The use of create_autospec()
The execution of the instruction create_autospec(socket.socket) creates a Mock object with the same methods of a real object socket.
The use of create_autospec(), in your code, is easier than the use of wraps.
The test class SocketTestCase
In the test class SocketTestCase(unittest.TestCase) are defined 3 methods:

method setUp() which defines the mock object mock_socket and the object server and client as you have done in your function test(mocker:MockFixture)
test_01: defines the method sendall() of mocked_socket and calls sender() of Comms
test_02: defines the method recv() of mocked_socket and calls receiver() of Comms

Instruction connection.timeout
In the code of the function receiver() you have used connection.timeout. I have substituted this instruction by Comms.timeout where timeout is an attribute defined in Comms.
